# Escape "double quotes" inside batch's input parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run the following in batch script where it takes an argument (a path)

```
runas /user:abc "icacls %1 /grant Everyone:(F) /T"
```

but the argument `%1` already contains a `"`  (because it's a path, passed on by context menu's Send To - I don't have much control over this).
So when the command runs in batch script it runs like this:

```
runas /user:abc "icacls "c:\folder" /grant Everyone:(F) /T"
```

So obviously I need to escape the `"`s created by `%1`. How do I perform string manipulation over `%1` such that it escaped the quotes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to use `\"` [Here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) is a site with a few other escape characters that you might find useful

To perform the string replace:

```
set temp=%1
set temp=%temp:"=\"%
echo %temp%
```

Comment: what if %1 is a path that contains spaces?

Comment: When do you use `""` over `\"`? I find batch files truly only escape with `""` and the `\"` version is only for non-batch programs (`runas` coded in C++ or some language that recognizes \ as an escape character). So do we only use `\"` when passing variables to non-batch programs and `""` when passing to other batch scripts (or batch functions (ex. `CALL :function "parameterWith""EscapedQuote"`)

Comment: @Mr_Moneybags, According to http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php, either one is a valid escape. I use `\"` over `""` simply because it's my preference since I work with c# primarily.

Comment: @nick but if you try the line `SET "var1=key=\"val&ue!\""`
you get the error `'ue!\""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

But `""` works.

Comment: @Mr_Moneybags, Odd. I wouldn't expect either to work since `&` should be escaped as `^&`. I'm wondering if maybe `""` tells the batch file "don't treat anything in this string as a special character" similar to placing `@` at the start of a string in c#. I'm not sure though, I haven't played with batch in forever

Comment: Hi I have same problem but above code not working for me. Can someone help?

Answer (score 7):

Each response covers part of the answer. Combining them using backslash & quote: `\"` you get:

```
runas /user:abc "icacls \"%~1\" /grant Everyone:(F) /T"
```

or you can doubled (double) quotes to escape them:

```
runas /user:abc "icacls ""%~1"" /grant Everyone:(F) /T"
```

---

As a side note `^` is occasionally useful for escaping special characters such as `<`, `|`, `>`, `||`, `&&`, and `&` For example:

```
echo ^|
```

but this is pretty rare.

Comment: Doubled double quotes does not work for me, but backslash does.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET myPath=%1
SET myPath=%myPath:"=\"%
runas /user:abc "icacls %myPath% /grant Everyone:(F) /T"
```

***Edit - The variable name was changed from `path` to `myPath`. PATH is a reserved system variable that should not be used for anything other than what it was intended.***

Comment: Do NOT use "path" as your variable - it is reserved for a special purpose in Windows. Modifying the value can cause problems later in the script. Change the variable name from "path" to something else, perhaps "mypath". Edit your answer and then I can up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

A search/replace isn't even needed in such cases. Just strip the original quotes from your argument (with `%~1`) - then you can add again whatever you want, e.g. the escaped quotes. In your example:

```
runas /user:abc "icacls \"%~1\" /grant Everyone:(F) /T"
```

Answer (score 0):

After some quick testing, this is the best method because it :

**Upside**

- handles multiple results output from tasklist
- handles application names with spaces if needed
- Can easily be changed to case sensitive / insensitive

**Downside**

- Calling more than one command which is technically slower

**Code**

```
@echo off    
set "EXE=authy desktop.exe"
tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %EXE%" | find /i "%EXE%" >nul 2>&1
If %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo %EXE% Is Running
) ELSE (
    echo %EXE% is Not Running
)
```

**Further Consideration**

You can change the  to && ( ) || ( ) formatting instead of checking errorlevel. Also you can use 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion' if errorlevel is used more than once by referencing with !errorlevel!.

```
tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %EXE%" | find /i "%EXE%" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo %EXE% Is Running
) || (
    echo %EXE% is Not Running
)
```