# Batch Script - Quotation marks inside a string

Tags: batch-file

I have the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  IF "%%A" EQU "call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers "\z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions" (
    TYPE D:\snapbuild\snapbuild.txt
  )
) >> temp.txt
move /y temp.txt %ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf
```

But this is giving the the wrong results, infact it doesn't appear to be doing anything at all.

How would I correctly use contain quotation marks in the script?

I have tried using '' on the outer quotations but this doesn't work.

Comment: Use the ^ escape character or double up on the double-quotes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893309/escape-double-quotes-inside-batchs-input-parameters) is what you're looking for.

Comment: None of the mentioned worked. Tried doubling quotes, tried ^" and also tried /"