# Escaping quotes in FOR /F Delimiters

Tags: batch-file

I have the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  IF "%%A" EQU "call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers "\z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions" (
    TYPE D:\snapbuild\snapbuild.txt
  )
) >> temp.txt
move /y temp.txt %ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf
```

The problem I have is the following section:

```
IF "%%A" EQU "call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers "\z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions" (
```

Isn't corretly escaping the inner quotation marks.

I have tried using /", ^", ""(Doubling quotes) but none of them are escaping the quotation marks.

How would I do this?

Comment: I think there is a quotation mark missing at the end of preprocessFileLineNumbers? As in `EQU "call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers"`

Comment: No I'm searching for: 
    call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers "\z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions

Comment: Make what is in the inner quotes a variable and then compare that in the if statement, instead.

Comment: Aah okay. Sorry, can't help then, :(

Comment: Actually, will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893309/escape-double-quotes-inside-batchs-input-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `"` and then make the test :

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  set "$Var=%%A"
  set "$Var=!$Var:"=!"
  IF "!$Var!"=="call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers \z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions" (
    TYPE D:\snapbuild\snapbuild.txt
  )
) >> temp.txt
move /y temp.txt %ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the solution of SachaDee should work, but it's also possible to compare it with quotes like jftuga mentions.
But then you need to use delayed expansion.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "search=call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers "\z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  IF "%%A" EQU "!search!" (
    TYPE D:\snapbuild\snapbuild.txt
  )
)
```

Comment: +1, but the file might contain `!`, which would require delayed expansion toggling.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that IF statement is failing? It works just fine for me without any escaping.

For example, the following results in `OK`:

```
IF "call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers "\z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions" EQU "call compile preprocessFileLineNumbers "\z\addons\dayz_code\init\compiles.sqf";             //Compile regular functions" (echo OK) else echo FAIL
```

It would be a different story if the inner quoted string contained any of the following because the parser would not see them as quoted:

- space
- `,`
- `;`
- `=`
- `&`
- `|`
- `<`
- `>`
- `)`
- `^`

Unfortunately, you cannot escape an internal `"` within a quoted string. Instead you must escape each of the above characters with a `^`.

But rather than doing that, I would probably use jeb's solution of comparing to a variable value using delayed expansion.